Does Postgres materialized view refresh view concurrently continue after client disconnect?
I have a materialize view that I update using REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY my_view using a Kubernetes cronjob that runs every 15 minutes. I'm experiencing a problem where it seems there are multiple refresh queries outstanding and waiting due to exclusive lock conflicts with each other. I do not allow the Kubernetes job to run concurrently (i.e. only one job connected to the database at a time). The job has a timeout of 15 minutes. I would have expected if the job timed out that the refresh query would have been terminated, but based on my observability that seems to not be the case. Is this expected for view refresh queries? Is this what happens on other types of queries (e.g. SELECT) on client disconnect)? If so, any suggestions for solving this so there is only one refresh running at a time?
This is running on Aurora PostgreSQL 12.12 if relevant.
Screenshot of Datadog database monitoring showing multiple active queries waiting on each other:


I cannot speak about Amazon Aurora, but I'll answer what would happen in PostgreSQL. Perhaps it is similar.
It seems that the job doesn't cancel the running query on the database when it times out. That is a problem, since the statement will continue running. Only when it is done and wants to reply to the client, it will notice that there is nobody on the other end of the line.
If you set tcp_keepalives_idle, tcp_keepalives_interval and tcp_keepalives_count low enough, the operating system will notice soon that the other side has hung up and end the connection. If you additionally set a low client_connection_check_interval, the server will cancel the query as soon as it realizes that the connection is dead. But all this will still take a while, so it is better to fix the job to correctly cancel the query when it times out.

Thank you for the helpful information! Any tips on what to do for "job to correctly cancel the query when it times out" on the client side?

Yes: write the program correctly, so that the client doesn't just die, but actively cancels the query. How you do that depends on your client API.
